# Why is this the image size in OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, opencv

[BitmapConverter.cs](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/src/OpenCvSharp.Extensions/BitmapConverter.cs) includes the function

```csharp
public static unsafe void ToBitmap(this Mat src, Bitmap dst)
```

later (on line 403) we have this fragment:

```csharp
uint imageSize = (uint)(src.DataEnd.ToInt64() - src.Data.ToInt64());
```

Looking at this diagram (from darkdragon-001's issue on the opencv GitHub [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8304#issuecomment-283697818)) I can't understand why the above line gets us the image size?

[image: explanatory image from GitHub]

Comment: Those two look like pointers, one to the beginning, the other to the position just past the end of the pixel array. Calculating the difference gives you the size of the array.

Comment: But not the size of the part of the array containing the image?

Comment: There's a bit of context missing, the `if` statement on line 401. This is called only when the image is not a submatrix (i.e. `data == datastart`) and when it's continuous. When it's not just one big contiguous chunk, it goes and copies row by row.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, if you write that up as the answer I'll mark it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this better, we need more context:

```
// ....
if (sstep == dstep && !submat && continuous)
{
    uint imageSize = (uint)(src.DataEnd.ToInt64() - src.Data.ToInt64());
    MemoryHelper.CopyMemory(pDst, pSrc, imageSize);
}
// ...
```

Ok, so this is code that deals with copying the raw memory containing the pixel data.

Those statements get executed only when:

- `sstep == dstep` -- The step size (offset between two consecutive rows in the memory) is same for source and destination
- `!submat` -- The source image is not a submatrix (meaning it's a full image, not a view of some bigger one, and thus `data == datastart`).
- `continuous` -- The source matrix is continuous (no padding between rows).

To summarize, it only runs when the underlying pixel array is one contiguous chunk of memory from `datastart` to `dataend`.

So that expression calculates the number of bytes between the two pointers `src.Data` and `src.DataEnd`.